# How is qt() implemented in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find out how `qt()` is implemented in R, but the commando `qt` without argument yields information that doesn't seem to help me much further:

```
function (p, df, ncp, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) 
        .External(C_qt, p, df, lower.tail, log.p)
    else .External(C_qnt, p, df, ncp, lower.tail, log.p)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000014f56158>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

So far I could only find that `.External` refers to a type of code. `C_qt` and `C_qnt` don't want to be found: https://www.google.com/search?q=C_qt&domains=r-project.org&sitesearch=r-project.org&btnG=Google+Search&gws_rd=ssl#domains=r-project.org&q=%22C_qt%22+site%3Ar-project.org

Does anybody know a way to extract the method used by `R` to approximate the quantile function? I don't mind complexity, I'm just really interested in the final expression and answer. `:-)`

Comment: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/qt.c

Comment: https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?q=qt&ref=cmdform